# Creating new column based on column values in row and column values in other rows in df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df below as:

```
id | name | status | country | ref_id
3    Bob    False    Germany    NaN
5    422     True    USA         3
7    Nick    False   India       NaN
6    Chris   True    Australia   7
8    324     True    Africa      28
28   Tim     False   Canada      53
```

I want to add a new column for each row, where if the status for that row is True,  if the ref_id for that row exists in the id column in another row and that rows status is False, give me the value of the name in that column.

So expected output below would be:

```
    id | name | status | country | ref_id | new
    3    Bob    False    Germany    NaN     NaN
    5    422     True    USA         3      Bob
    7    Nick    False   India       NaN    NaN
    6    Chris   True    Australia   7      Nick
    8    324     True    Africa      28     Tim
    28   Tim     False   Canada      53     NaN
```

I have code below that I am using for other purposes that just filters for rows that have a **status** of **True**, and and **id_reference** value that exists in the **id column** like below:

```
(df.loc[df["status"]&df["id_reference"].astype(float).isin(df.loc[~df["status"], "id"])])
```

But I am trying to also calculate a new column as mentioned prior above with the value of the name if it has one in that column

Thanks!

Comment: If the status of the column is False and you want the name value, then how the expected output contains NaN for id=3? It would be 'Bob'.

Comment: it is NaN for id = 3 because for id = 3 there is no ref_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['new']=df.loc[df.status,'ref_id'].map(df.set_index('id')['name'])
df
   id   name  status    country  ref_id   new
0   3    Bob   False    Germany     NaN   NaN
1   5    422    True        USA     3.0   Bob
2   7   Nick   False      India     NaN   NaN
3   6  Chris    True  Australia     7.0  Nick
4   8    324    True     Africa    28.0   Tim
5  28    Tim   False     Canada    53.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This essentially a merge:

```
merged = (df.loc[df['status'],['ref_id']]
            .merge(df.loc[~df['status'],['id','name']], left_on='ref_id', right_on='id')
         )

df['ref_id'] = (df['id'].map(merged.set_index('id')['name'])
                        .where(df['status'])
               )
```